# using custom component in dynamic created reactive forms in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component where I am using Formbuilder to build controls dynamically

Nominatecomponent.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'nominate',  
templateUrl: './nominate.html',
})
export class NominateComponent{  
  myForm: FormGroup;  
  constructor(
     private fb: FormBuilder
   ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  // build the form model
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
   items: this.fb.array([])
  })
}

 submit() {
  console.log("Reactive Form submitted: ", this.myForm)
}

 buildItem(val: string) {
  return new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(val, Validators.required),      
  quantity: new FormControl(val, Validators.required)
 })
}

addRow(): void{
const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['items'];
control.push(this.buildItem(''));
}
}
```

Nominate.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">   
    <fieldset formArrayName="items">                    
      <div class="form-group row"
           *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('items').controls; let i=index"
           [formGroup]="item">
        <div class="col-sm-6">                            
           <lookup [attr.id]="'dog'+i" formControlName ="dog"></lookup>            
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>               
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Submit" [disabled]="myForm?.invalid">
    </div>
  </form>
  <h6 class="mt-3">FormGroup Model (<code>myForm.value</code>)</h6>
  <div><pre><code>{{ myForm?.value | json }}</code></pre></div>
```

Here,  I want to add a custom component 'lookup' instead of  input- text.

```
<lookup></lookup>
```

but I am not sure how to add it as a -part of the form group. I tried several online links but all in vain .

Lookup component

```
@Component({
      selector : 'lookup',
      templateUrl : './lookup.html',
      providers : [LookupService]})
export class DogLookupComponent{
      results: Object;
      searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();
      @Input() group: FormGroup;

      constructor(private LookUpService: LookupService){
                this.LookUpService.searchDogs(this.searchTerm$)
                .subscribe(results => {
                          this.results = results;
                });
      }
```

}

lookup.html

```
<input (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search..." type="text" class="input-group-sm col-sm-12"  [(ngModel)]= "selectedText">
<div *ngIf="results" class="col-sm-12" style="min-height:200px; overflow-y: auto;">                 
      <div *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:5" class="row clickbox" (click)="selectItem(result.Id)">                                                  
                <mat-list style="width:100%">
                          <mat-list-item>
                                    <td class="col-sm-5"> {{ result.Name }}  </td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-3"> {{ result.quantity }} </td>                                        
                          </mat-list-item>
                          <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                </mat-list>
      </div>
```

I tried creating an input and passing it as the group. Tried a couple of things. I am quite new to Angular and trying to explore features within Angular.

Comment: What happens when you enter the <lookup></lookup> in the html?

Comment: I get an error in console NominateComponent.html:33 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'name'

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to your lookup component. Please share your code in your nominate component where you have defined your form.

Comment: I have edited nominate component, pls could you  help

Comment: Are you still getting the same error with the updated code you just posted? If yes, post your nominate component ts code also.

Comment: Yes,getting same error,I have posted nominate component.ts code. TIA

Comment: Your addRow and buildItem functions seem to add form controls to form array but they are never called. Why is that?

Comment: if you get an error "No value accessor for form control with name" is because your custom form control it's not a "custom form control". to make a custom form control check, e.g. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html